# site down - Fatal error: includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php on line 434

Tags: magento

My site become completely inaccesible. Opening both frontend and backend gives same error message..

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /home/decoplan/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php on line 434

Site: decoplanters.co.uk 
Magento 1.5.1 Error -

I have cleared the var/cache however the problem still exists.

I hope someone can help as all 4 sites are down.

Kind regards 
Prano

Comment: Did you clear the right cache folder? Are you certain that Magento was writting to var/cache and not to your OS temp directory?

Comment: do you mean the TEMP/var/cache? I deleted the files in the /var/cache folder. Is this correct?

Comment: Only if it's creating them there. 9 out of 10 times if I have problems like this I discover that var/cache isn't writable by the Apache user and it instead writing the cache files to /tmp/magento (this would assume a unix system).

Comment: I have check the tmp folder in the root and there is no /tmp/magento folder  in our set up. We have just moved our server to a new server, however everything was working fine until about an hour ago.

Answer (score 0):

Try empty database cache by running this sql statement

```
TRUNCATE TABLE `core_cache`
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Hi I have tried this however it does not work. What I did was disable the complier on config.php in includes folder. I now have the following error message. Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in /home/decoplan/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php on line 434