# Magento, Fatal error, 'Call to ... getAllOptions() on a non-object ... Core\Model\Cache.php'

Tags: magento

After adding to my frontend/default/[theme]/ folder I hit an error where the site would no longer load. I removed the offending file, but the site still won't load. Enabling PHP error output leads to this message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAllOptions() on a non-object in C:\websites\[snip]\htdocs\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php on line 449
```

I have cleared the cache, and nothing is being created in the var/cache folder when pages are (attempted to be) loaded... Any ideas what else could be cached somewhere?

Also note, this has taken both the frontend and backend offline, so I have no access to the admin system.

This appears to be the same problem mentioned here ([site down - Fatal error: includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Cache.php on line 434](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979305/site-down-fatal-error-includes-src-mage-core-model-cache-php-on-line-434)). I don't have the compiler enabled though, so the error is directly in Core/Model/Cache.php.

Comment: Are your permissions set correctly on /var/cache?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In my case this problem occured because my **app/etc/config.xml** file was missing.
Try to see if your XML's config files are there.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you Ricardo, you were spot on. Turns out during my frantic debugging I managed to remove the line that told Mage where the /app/etc folder was (this site stores it outside the webroot), so even after I fixed the problem (in the DB, the cache was still enabled, but it wasn't being used/refreshed) the site still didn't work. Sorted now though, and I know so much more about Magento's inner-workings!

Comment: Perfect! as this file was in the GIT .ignore list  ;-) hehe

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

copy app/etc/config.xml from original magento to your magento.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to fix it (It worked for me after lot of research):

```
chmod 644 app/etc/config.xml
chmod 755 app/etc
chmod 755 app/etc/modules

rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```